# How do I customize Bootstrap 4 for Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I've installed Bootstrap 4 via [the Twitter Bootstrap Gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem). Following the instructions in the `README.md`, I've been able to get Bootstrap working. Now I need to customize/modify it.

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#introduction) gives some indication how to do that, but it's not clear how it works in a Rails context. All I want to do is just change some of the colors.

That should be easy, right? I mean, I shouldn't have to actually change any of the Bootstrap files, right? I can just import a SASS file easily and swap out a value while still gaining the advantage of using an updatable gem to make sure that Bootstrap itself is updateable, right? ☹️ *(It's not easy at all.)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I mostly prefer that way. 
Import bootstrap and then override what you need or I add additional classes containing changes, but in some cases that may require a lot of !important elements. And that's not the best way to do things.